# May i know call rest api angular js

Tags: angularjs, https, reshape, angular-resource

This is the url I am working with: http://103.13.75.21:8081/product

I have tried:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http({
    method : "GET",
    url : "http://103.13.75.21:8081/product"
  }).then(function mySucces(response) {
      $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
    }, function myError(response) {
      $scope.myWelcome = response;
  });
});
</script>

{"data":null,
 "status":-1,
 "config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest"[null],
 "transformResponse":[null],
  "url":"http://103.13.75.21:8081/product","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":""}
```

May I know how to get `product id` by using `$resource` or `$http`?

Comment: code looks good, you may need to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin on your backend (103.13.75.21).

Comment: API isn't CORS enabled if you are making request from another domain...look at error in browser console